# How can I export the coordinates of selected object vertices to a CSV file?

Tags: python, scripting, export, csv

I need to save the vertex locations of selected objects in Blender to use as offset values in another application.
Ideally, I would like to have these as a CSV file (either as x, y, z per column or a vector in a column, doesn't matter - even better would be object name per row: `object.000 | x | y | z` )

Is this something doable thru a script or an addon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module to save the data. In the following example I save a file with file name `objects-data.csv` to desktop containing all the vertex data for all selected objects.

```
import bpy
import csv
from os import path as p

selected_objects = bpy.context.selected_objects
output_path = p.join(p.expanduser("~/Desktop"), "objects-data.csv")

with open(output_path, "w", newline='') as output:
    csv = csv.writer(output, delimiter='|')
    csv.writerow(["Name", "X", "Y", "Z"])

    for obj in selected_objects:
        for v in obj.data.vertices:
            x, y, z = v.co
            csv.writerow([obj.name, x, y, z])

print(f"Data exported to: {output_path}")
```

Take note that I used `csv.writer(output, delimiter='|')` to specify the delimitter to a pipe symbol instead of the default comma symbol. So if you open the file in a spreadsheet program you will have to explicitly tell the program which delimiter to use if you use a delimiter other than comma.

Or use this script that saves a plain text file without `csv` module:

```
import bpy
from os import path as p

selected_objects = bpy.context.selected_objects
output_path = p.join(p.expanduser("~/Desktop"), "objects-data.csv")

with open(output_path, "w") as output:
    output.write("Name | X | Y | Z\n")

    for obj in selected_objects:
        for v in obj.data.vertices:
            x, y, z = v.co
            output.write(f"{obj.name} | {x} | {y} | {z}\n")

print(f"Data exported to: {output_path}")
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect an answer that quickly! It's exactly what I was looking for - thank you very much; saved me hours of ctrl-c/v!

Comment: Edit: well I need the object locations instead of the vertices' locations, but that was easy to do once I had this, thanks again

Comment: oh ok. oops sorry i edited your post to use vertex locations. well anyway im glad u found it useful and also it's still useful for other community members when they find this thread 