# XYZ-Property Point Set Export

Tags: export, point-clouds

Is it possible to export an ASCII/CSV file (or use python,) to obtain the X, Y, Z and colour property for a regular 3D mesh? If so where are the points referenced to?  The corner or centre of cell? Can subsurface colour properties also be included?

Looking to obtain data in the format:

```
X
Y
Z
Red
Green
Blue
15847, 28635, 1548, 255, 0, 0,
15847, 28635, 1549, 250, 0, 0,
15847, 28635, 1550, 245, 0, 0,
....
```

Many thanks,

ARW

Comment: HEX colour code would also be fine.

Comment: Which corner or center of a "cell" are you referring to? What "colour property for a regular mesh"? A mesh object can have an object color which can be shown in the viewport in _Solid_ shading, or a material can have its own material color to be shown in _Solid Shading_, then it's possible for an object to have multiple materials and each can have multicolored image textures or multicolored procedural textures... what exactly is it that you want?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/299182/how-can-i-export-the-coordinates-of-selected-object-vertices-to-a-csv-file